# Pyhon str型のデータの文字コードを判別して、改行コードなどを正しく表示したい。

Tags: python, python3

＜やりたいこと＞
　ある通信データをstr型で引き渡すようになっています。
　str型変数の中身のエンコードを判別して、正しく日本語表示および改行を整えて、表示したいです。実際の出力先はtk.Textですが、printでの出力でも同じことなので、ひとまずprintで正しく表示したいと考えています。

＜問題点＞
通信データは、日本語文字列をUTF-8でエンコードしているため、str型でUTF-8のエンコード文字列が渡されます。
具体的には、

```py
>>>t = 'こんにちは'
>>>bt8 = t.encode('utf-8')
>>>bt8
b'\xe3\x81\x93\xe3\x82\x93\xe3\x81\xab\xe3\x81\xa1\xe3\x81\xaf'
とエンコードされますが、
>>>data = '\xe3\x81\x93\xe3\x82\x93\xe3\x81\xab\xe3\x81\xa1\xe3\x81\xaf'
このように本来bytes型で扱いたいコードがstr型となっています。
```

１．文字列をUTF-8だと判断する。今回はUTF-8ですが、S-JISなどの可能性もあり得ます。
２．str型→bytes型へ文字列の表現のまま変換する。
３．bytes型を①の判別した結果から適切なdecodeで文字列に戻す。
こういった手順になると思います。あるいは２，１が逆かもしれませんが。
解決方法が分からず困っています。

ご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教示をお願いいたします。

Comment: [chardet](https://chardet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) というモジュールで判定が出来るようです。[chardet 文字コードを判定する](https://www.python.ambitious-engineer.com/archives/750), [Pythonのchardetモジュールが、“testあ”という文字列（UTF-8）の文字コードを“Windows-1254”だと判定する](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/48793/26370)

Comment: [cChardet](https://pypi.org/project/cchardet/) というのもあって、こちらの方が高速らしいです。[Python3.3.1でcChardetとpython3-chardetを使ったメモ](https://qiita.com/katryo/items/0e3b1b2c784a4a955927)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下あたりの記事から関数をつくってみました。
簡単なテストしかしていないので、バグ等あると思います。
本当に使うならいろんなパターンで試して、改良等もやっておいてください。

[Process escape sequences in a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4020539/9014308) / [参考にした回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24519338/9014308)
[how do I .decode('string-escape') in Python3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14820429/9014308) / [参考にした回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15528611/9014308)

質問の`2.`の部分を以下に作成しました。
元のデータは`str`と`bytes`のどちらでも使えます。
ASCIIの範囲(～0x7F)を超えた文字やコードポイントがあった場合の処理を`encoding`,`errors`パラメータで指定可能にしています。
複数の`encoding`が混在するようなデータは扱えません。

```
import re

UNESCAPE_ENCODE_RE = re.compile(b'''
  \\\\( U[0-9A-Fa-f]{8} # 8-digit hex escapes
      | u[0-9A-Fa-f]{4} # 4-digit hex escapes
      | x[0-9A-Fa-f]{2} # 2-digit hex escapes
      | [0-7]{1,3}   # Octal escapes
      | N\{[^}]+\}   # Unicode characters by name
      | \\\\         # Backslash escape
      | [\'"abfnrtv] # Single-character escapes
      | .   # Other undefined character escapes
      | $   # ?? bogus escape (end of line) ??
      )''', re.VERBOSE)

def unescape_encode(data, encoding='UTF-8', errors='backslashreplace'):

  def unescape(m):

    b = m.group(1)

    if len(b) == 0:
      raise ValueError("Invalid character escape: '\\'.")
    i = b[0]
    if i == 85 or i == 117: # U00000000-Uffffffff/UFFFFFFFF, u0000-uffff/uFFFF
      return chr(int(b[1:], 16)).encode(encoding, errors)
    elif i == 120:      # x00-xff/xFF
      v = int(b[1:], 16)
    elif 48 <= i <= 55: # 0-777
      v = int(b, 8)
    elif i == 78:       # N{.*} Unicode characters by name
      return (b'\\' + b).decode('unicode-escape').encode(encoding, errors)
    elif i == 34: return b'"'
    elif i == 39: return b"'"
    elif i == 92: return b'\\'
    elif i == 97: return b'\a'
    elif i == 98: return b'\b'
    elif i == 102: return b'\f'
    elif i == 110: return b'\n'
    elif i == 114: return b'\r'
    elif i == 116: return b'\t'
    elif i == 118: return b'\v'
    else:
      s = b.decode('ascii')
      raise UnicodeDecodeError(
        'stringescape', data, m.start(), m.end(), "Invalid escape: %r" % s
      )

    return bytes((v, ))

  if isinstance(data, bytes):
    workbytes = data
  elif isinstance(data, str):
    workbytes = bytes(data, encoding, errors)
  else:
    raise TypeError

  return UNESCAPE_ENCODE_RE.sub(unescape, workbytes)
```

で、コメントにも書いた記事を元に`1.`と`3.`の処理を以下の様に行います。
[Python3.3.1でcChardetとpython3-chardetを使ったメモ](https://qiita.com/katryo/items/0e3b1b2c784a4a955927)

```
import cchardet

f = open('EscapedSjis.txt') # 何か適当にエスケープ化したテキストをファイルにしておきます。
data = f.read()
f.close()

# 上記の代りに data = '\xe3\x81\x93\xe3\x82\x93\xe3\x81\xab\xe3\x81\xa1\xe3\x81\xaf' でも良い

unescapedbytes = unescape_encode(data)     # 2. str/bytesのエスケープ表現を解除して文字コード化
detected = cchardet.detect(unescapedbytes) # 1. bytesデータを解析してencodingを判定
print(detected)

if detected['confidence'] > 0.8: # 確度情報を元に処理を変えてみる
  print(unescapedbytes.decode(detected['encoding'])) # 3. 検出したencodingでdecode
else:
  print(unescapedbytes.decode(detected['encoding'], 'replace')) # encoding不能な文字は?に置換
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。試してみます。